# Click issue on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, click

I have some Javascript opening a modal window containing a Vimeo video but I'm having some issue with iPads on the click function (obviously) but my javascript skills aren't strong enough to confidently make the correct change.

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('body').live('click',function(){
                if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
                    $('div[id*=myModal] iframe').each(function() {
                        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
                    });
                };                                      
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Would someone please help with making this iPad friendly. The click function in the third line is the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: use:) `.live('click touchstart'`

Comment: thanks Bhojendra. I've just added this to the code and waiting to test. Will let you know how this goes. Thank you for such a quick response.